# Error: Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm unable to restore my backup DB on heroku DB but I don't have any issue if I restore on my local env and I get no errors.

When I try to restore on heroku connect database I get this following error:

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_restore.exe --host
>   XXXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com --port 5432 --username
>   "XXXXokwpyzewicl" --dbname "d9uto7paqXXX" --no-password  --verbose
>
> "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\loans.backup"
>
> pg_restore: connecting to
>   database for restore pg_restore: implied data-only restore
>
> pg_restore: processing data for table "application_denial_reason_types"
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 5202; 0 16622 TABLE DATA application_denial_reason_types postgres
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "application_denial_reason_types" does not exist 
>   Command was: COPY application_denial_reason_types (denial_reason_type_id, denial_reason_type_name, description, active, created_by, creat... pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET application_denial_reason_types_denial_reason_type_id_seq
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 5672; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET
>   application_denial_reason_types_denial_reason_type_id_seq postgres
>
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation
>   "application_denial_reason_types_denial_reason_type_id_seq" does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('application_denial_reason_types_de...
>                                    ^
>       Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('application_denial_reason_types_denial_reason_type_id_seq',
>   1, false);

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to set value of not existing sequence:

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: relation
>   "application_denial_reason_types_denial_reason_type_id_seq" does not
>   exist

to understand the reason take alook at the:

> pg_restore: connecting to database for restore pg_restore: implied
>   data-only restore

If you check `man pg_restore` you'll find, that:

> ```
>    -a
>    --data-only
>        Restore only the data, not the schema (data definitions). Table data, large objects, and sequence values are restored, if
> ```
>
> present in the archive.

So you probably have data structure on your local env, and this is why you set value for existing sequence. And there is not structure on heroku, so you get error.

Remove `-a` from `pg_restore` command to run DDL prior to data restore.